# Как заставить python понимать unicode. При чтении из файла ошибка: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, unicode

Приветствую! Как заставить питон читать из файла и выводить любые юникод символы?Типа такого всякого разного.  ←↑→↓↔↕↖↗↘↙↚↛↜↝↞↟. 
При попытке просто прочитать

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f = open("unicode_symbols.txt", "r")
        for s in f:
            print(u""+s)
            print("\n")
```

выводит следующую ошибку

```
  return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 18: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: в какой кодировке текст в файле закодирован? Если вам слово кодировка ничего не говорит, то просто вставьте в вопрос байты минимального файла, который к ошибке приводит: `print(open("unicode_symbols.txt", "rb").read())`

Comment: codecs.open мне по душе

Comment: @eri: `codecs.open()` не нужен ни на Питон 2 (`io.open()`) ни на Питон 3 (где  `io.open()` доступна как встроенная `open()`)

Comment: @jfs семантика другая

Comment: @eri: верно, codecs.open хуже.

Comment: @jfs как скажите.

Comment: @eri: если у вас есть доводы об обратном, то я слушаю, чем вы обосновываете использование `codecs.open()` на текстовом файле  вместо рекомендуемой разработчиками встроенной `open()`.

Comment: @jfs ,без модуля codecs доступны не все кодировки.

Comment: @eri: приведите пример для текстового файла.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте для начала указать кодировку файла при чтении явно.

```
f = open("unicode_symbols.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8')
```

и - все получится!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну если не верите - попробуйте еще такой код:

```
# BEGIN NUMERICS_DEMO
import unicodedata

sample = '1\xbc\xb2\u0969\u136b\u216b\u2466\u2480\u3285'

f = open("F:\\PyCodes\\WOW\\utf8_rows.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8')
for char in sample:
    _ = 'U+%04x' % ord(char) + char.center(6)  + unicodedata.name(char) 
    f.write(_)
for s in f:
    print(u""+s)
# END NUMERICS_DEMO
```

Ну понятное дело - путь к своему файлу нарисуйте =D
У меня на печати это:

```
U+0031  1   DIGIT ONE

U+00bc  ¼   VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER

U+00b2  ²   SUPERSCRIPT TWO

U+0969  ३   DEVANAGARI DIGIT THREE

U+136b  ፫   ETHIOPIC DIGIT THREE

U+216b  Ⅻ   ROMAN NUMERAL TWELVE

U+2466  ⑦   CIRCLED DIGIT SEVEN

U+2480  ⒀   PARENTHESIZED NUMBER THIRTEEN

U+3285  ㊅   CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH SIX
```

Comment: пробовал уже, бесполезно

Comment: @Art а у меня - работает )))

Comment: @Art тогда давайте точное содержимое вашего файла в байтах (не символах)

Comment: нет уж - лучше вы )